# module as folder, but index.js under the folder only contains some require statements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning the source code of hexo, a project based on node.js.
And there is a file init.js:

```
if (results.config){
require('./plugins/tag');
require('./plugins/deployer');
require('./plugins/processor');
require('./plugins/helper');
require('./plugins/filter');
require('./plugins/generator');
}
```

why these require statements have no reference? So I checked each index.js under these folder(e.g. tag), the index.js is looking like:

```
require('./init');
require('./config');
require('./generate');
require('./server');
require('./deploy');
require('./migrate');
require('./new');
require('./routes');
require('./version');
require('./render');
```

No exports found. I am wondering how these requires work.

Comment: I have read this. Thank you for the comment but it does not explain my confuse.

Comment: @Paul, you're correct. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source you're talking about, and the basic answer to your question is that the code in those requires gets run.  Normally, you're right that you need to have some kind of export to make use of objects inside those files, but hexo is being a bit nonstandard.

Instead of having each module be independent and fairly agnostic (except via requires), what they're doing is creating an object called 'extend' (look in extend.js) then each of those individual files (e.g. ./init, ./migrate, etc) require extend.js and hang new objects and functions on it in a sort of namespaced fashion.

If you look at the end of those files you'll see something calls to extend.tag.register and others.  Modules are cached when required, so in practice it acts something like a singleton in other languages the way they're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul points out, the requires you see should be considered as functional units themselves, rather than returning any useful values. Each of the files calls an function to modify an internal state.